# AlertDialog isn't displaying

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-alertdialog

I have the following code.

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .SetMessage (message)
    .SetPositiveButton ("Yes", delegate {

                })
    .SetNegativeButton ("No", delegate {

                })
    .Show ();
```

I set a breakpoint on the first line (or rather, the beginning on the only line) and it was triggered. However, the `AlertDialog` never displayed. The code set to execute after the dialog showed was never reached.

This is in MainActivity.cs, so `this` is referencing the correct object

Comment: How did you fixed this problem? I'm getting the same thing. It was working a while ago, now it's not.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you forgot

```
Builder(this).----your stuff---.build().show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setMessage("Message you want");




    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {


   }



    });

    builder.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

try that

call

```
alert();

void alert(){
     AlertDialog.Builder myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            myAlertDialog.setTitle("Start Internet");
            myAlertDialog.setMessage("Please check internet connection.Do you want go to Setting?");

            myAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Myeditprofile.class);

                    startActivity(intent);
                    //  finish();


                }

            });

            myAlertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
       // finish();
                }
            });
            myAlertDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@wilson try this, I tested and this is working code.

```
AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        ad.setMessage("Message");
        ad.setCancelable(true); //If you need..
        ad.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //ToDo Code                 
            }
        });             
        ad.setNegativeButton("No", null);  // Add method as above if you want
        AlertDialog alert = ad.create();
        alert.show();
```